# HQL Like doesn't return anything

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Im trying to do a pretty simple HQL query, like I've done times before.

I for some reason fail to find any problems with following query

```
@Query(value = "FROM SearchCustomer c WHERE c.code =:searchParam OR c.name1 LIKE '%:searchParam%')
```

and SO threads seem to give same solution, so why is `LIKE` not returning anything?

Full match c.code works fine. I tried passing in "AAR", "Aar", "aar" to retrieve name1 "AARHUS" but the size of the returned list is always 0.

Comment: It's a good idea to translate HQL to SQL and run it with the same parameters against your database, see what happens.

Comment: remove the `'` around the `%:searchParam%`.

Comment: I would try something like: `c.name1 LIKE CONCAT('%', :searchParam, '%')`

Comment: @luk2302, thanks, this solves the problem. add this as a answer for points! cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `'` surrounding your `%:searchParam%`:

```
@Query(value = "FROM SearchCustomer c WHERE c.code =:searchParam OR c.name1 LIKE %:searchParam%)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ' ' from your HQL

```
@Query(value = "FROM SearchCustomer c WHERE c.code =:searchParam OR c.name1 LIKE %:searchParam%)
```

So, the above query will return the words containing "searchParam" text